# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized in Tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, classification, tensorflow

I am working through the [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html), which uses a "weird" format to upload the data. I would like to use the NumPy or pandas format for the data, so that I can compare it with scikit-learn results.

I get the digit recognition data from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data.

Here the code from the TensorFlow tutorial (which works fine):

```
# Stuff from tensorflow tutorial 
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Here I read the data, strip out the target variables and split the data into testing and training datasets (this all works fine):

```
# Read dataframe from training data
csvfile='train.csv'
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
df = read_csv(csvfile)

# Strip off the target data and make it a separate dataframe.
Target = df.label
del df["label"]

# Split data into training and testing sets
msk = np.random.rand(len(df)) < 0.8
dfTest = df[~msk]
TargetTest = Target[~msk]
df = df[msk]
Target = Target[msk]

# One hot encode the target
OHTarget=pd.get_dummies(Target)
OHTargetTest=pd.get_dummies(TargetTest)
```

Now, when I try to run the training step, I get a `FailedPreconditionError`:

```
for i in range(100):
    batch = np.array(df[i*50:i*50+50].values)
    batch = np.multiply(batch, 1.0 / 255.0)
    Target_batch = np.array(OHTarget[i*50:i*50+50].values)
    Target_batch = np.multiply(Target_batch, 1.0 / 255.0)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch, y_: Target_batch})
```

Here's the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-967faab7d494> in <module>()
      4     Target_batch = np.array(OHTarget[i*50:i*50+50].values)
      5     Target_batch = np.multiply(Target_batch, 1.0 / 255.0)
----> 6     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch, y_: Target_batch})

/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in run(self, feed_dict, session)
   1265         none, the default session will be used.
   1266     """
-> 1267     _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
   1268
   1269

/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc in _run_using_default_session(operation, feed_dict, graph, session)
   2761                        "the operation's graph is different from the session's "
   2762                        "graph.")
-> 2763   session.run(operation, feed_dict)
   2764
   2765

/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict)
    343
    344     # Run request and get response.
--> 345     results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
    346
    347     # User may have fetched the same tensor multiple times, but we

/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict)
    417         # pylint: disable=protected-access
    418         raise errors._make_specific_exception(node_def, op, e.error_message,
--> 419                                               e.code)
    420         # pylint: enable=protected-access
    421       raise e_type, e_value, e_traceback

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1
     [[Node: gradients/add_grad/Shape_1 = Shape[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_1)]]
Caused by op u'gradients/add_grad/Shape_1', defined at:
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    ...........

...which was originally created as op u'add', defined at:
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
[elided 17 identical lines from previous traceback]
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-45-59183d86e462>", line 1, in <module>
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 403, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 44, in add
    return _op_def_lib.apply_op("Add", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 633, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/user32/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 95):

The `FailedPreconditionError` arises because the program is attempting to read a variable (named `"Variable_1"`) before it has been initialized. In TensorFlow, all variables must be explicitly initialized, by running their "initializer" operations. For convenience, you can run all of the variable initializers in the current session by executing the following statement before your training loop:

```
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
```

Note that this answer assumes that, as in the question, you are using `tf.InteractiveSession`, which allows you to run operations without specifying a session. For non-interactive uses, it is more common to use `tf.Session`, and initialize as follows:

```
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
```

Comment: Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` instead because `tf.initialize_all_variables()` will be deprecated.

Answer (score 64):

`tf.initialize_all_variables()` is deprecated. Instead initialize tensorflow variables with:

```
tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

A common example usage is:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Comment: what's the difference between sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) and tf.global_variables_initializer()? you often see the latter

Comment: @dv3 like everything else in TensorFlow, there is a difference between creating the operation and running it. I think that's why "initialize_all_variables" was replaced with "global_variables_initializer": The name "initialize_all_variables" sounds like it does it, when it only creates the operation.

Comment: pls note that the method is now tf.initialize_all_variables()

Comment: @jesses.co.tt - answer is correct; `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is the one deprecated. See: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initialize_all_variables

Comment: @user3144836's answer worked perfectly.

In my case, I encapsulated the entire code block under the with routine, and that purged all the errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

From official documentation, [FailedPreconditionError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/FailedPreconditionError)

> This exception is most commonly raised when running an operation that
>   reads a tf.Variable before it has been initialized.

In your case the error even explains what variable was not initialized: `Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_1`. One of the TF tutorials explains a lot about variables, their [creation/initialization/saving/loading](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables)

Basically to initialize the variable you have 3 options:

- initialize all global variables with [`tf.global_variables_initializer()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer)
- initialize variables you care about with [`tf.variables_initializer(list_of_vars)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer). Notice that you can use this function to mimic global_variable_initializer: `tf.variable_initializers(tf.global_variables())`
- initialize only one variable with `var_name.initializer`

I almost always use the first approach. Remember you should put it inside a session run. So you will get something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

If your are curious about more information about variables, read [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops) to know how to `report_uninitialized_variables` and check `is_variable_initialized`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize variables before using them.​

If you try to evaluate the variables before initializing them you'll run into:
`FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value tensor.`

The easiest way is initializing all variables at once using: `tf.global_variables_initializer()`

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
```

You use `sess.run(init)` to run the initializer, without fetching any value.

To initialize only a subset of variables, you use `tf.variables_initializer()` listing the variables:

```
var_ab = tf.variables_initializer([a, b], name="a_and_b")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(var_ab)
```

You can also initialize each variable separately using `tf.Variable.initializer`

```
# create variable W as 784 x 10 tensor, filled with zeros
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10])) with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(W.initializer)
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message from a completely different case. It seemed that the exception handler in tensorflow raised it. You can check each row in the Traceback. In my case, it happened in `tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py`, because this file contained a different bug, where `self.__mode` and `self.__name` weren't initialized, and it needed to call `self._FileIO__mode`, and `self_FileIO__name` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Different use case, but set your session as the default session did the trick for me:

```
with sess.as_default():
    result = compute_fn([seed_input,1])
```

This is one of these mistakes that is so obvious, once you have solved it.

My use-case is the following: 
1) store keras VGG16 as tensorflow graph 
2) load kers VGG16 as a graph 
3) run tf function on the graph and get:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value block1_conv2/bias
     [[Node: block1_conv2/bias/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@block1_conv2/bias"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block1_conv2/bias)]]
     [[Node: predictions/Softmax/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_168_predictions/Softmax", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The **FailedPreconditionError** comes because the session is trying to read a variable that hasn"t been initialized.

As of *Tensorflow* version 1.11.0, you need to take this :

```
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Tensorflow 2.0 Compatible Answer**: In Tensorflow Version >= 2.0, the command for Initializing all the Variables if we use Graph Mode, to fix the **`FailedPreconditionError`** is shown below:

```
tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer
```

This is just a shortcut for `variables_initializer(global_variables())`

It returns an Op that initializes global variables in the graph.

Comment: I still see this error even after initializing in 2.3 when using with `tf.data`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094061/failedpreconditionerror-getnext-failed-because-the-iterator-has-not-been-init

Answer (score 3):

With tensorflow version >3.2 you may use this command:

```
x1 = tf.Variable(5)
y1 = tf.Variable(3)

z1 = x1 + y1

init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    print(sess.run(z1))
```

The output: 8 
will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

When I had this issue with `tf.train.string_input_producer()` and `tf.train.batch()` initializing the local variables before I started the Coordinator solved the problem. I had been getting the error when I initialized the local variables after starting the Coordinator.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly something has changed in recent TensorFlow builds, because for me, running

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

before fitting any models seems to do the trick.  Most older examples and comments seem to suggest `tf.global_variables_initializer()`.