# Not initialized variable in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, training-data

I am trying to write a machine learning program. The idea was to train a model (defined in *q_model*) which could be trained with RMSProp. I report here a really simplified version of my code, which is not working.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

#--------------------------------------
# Model definition
#--------------------------------------

# Let's use a simple nn for the Q value function

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,10],dtype=tf.float64), name='W')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10],dtype=tf.float64), name='b')

def q_model(X,A):
    input = tf.concat((X,A), axis=1)
    return tf.reduce_sum( tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, W) + b), axis=1)

#--------------------------------------
# Model and model initializer
#--------------------------------------

optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.9)
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)

#--------------------------------------
# Learning
#--------------------------------------

x = np.matrix(np.random.uniform((0.,0.),(1.,1.), (1000,2)))
a = np.matrix(np.random.uniform((0),(1), 1000)).T
y = np.matrix(np.random.uniform((0),(1), 1000)).T

y_batch , x_batch, a_batch = tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,1), name='y'), tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,2), name='x'), tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,1), name='a')
error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_batch - q_model(x_batch,a_batch))) / 100.
train = optimizer.minimize(error)

indx = range(1000)
for i in range(100):
    # batches
    np.random.shuffle(indx)
    indx = indx[:100]
    print sess.run({'train':train}, feed_dict={'x:0':x[indx],'a:0':a[indx],'y:0':y[indx]})
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samuele/Projects/GBFQI/test/tf_test.py", line 45, in <module>
    print sess.run({'train':train}, feed_dict={'x:0':x[indx],'a:0':a[indx],'y:0':y[indx]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value b/RMSProp
     [[Node: RMSProp/update_b/ApplyRMSProp = ApplyRMSProp[T=DT_DOUBLE, _class=["loc:@b"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](b, b/RMSProp, b/RMSProp_1, RMSProp/update_b/Cast, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_1, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_2, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_3, gradients/add_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]

Caused by op u'RMSProp/update_b/ApplyRMSProp', defined at:
  File "/home/samuele/Projects/GBFQI/test/tf_test.py", line 38, in <module>
    train = optimizer.minimize(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 325, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 456, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 97, in update_op
    return optimizer._apply_dense(g, self._v)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py", line 140, in _apply_dense
    use_locking=self._use_locking).op
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/gen_training_ops.py", line 449, in apply_rms_prop
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value b/RMSProp
     [[Node: RMSProp/update_b/ApplyRMSProp = ApplyRMSProp[T=DT_DOUBLE, _class=["loc:@b"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](b, b/RMSProp, b/RMSProp_1, RMSProp/update_b/Cast, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_1, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_2, RMSProp/update_b/Cast_3, gradients/add_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]
```

I cannot explain myself this error since the model is initialized, and actually if I run

```
print sess.run(q_model(x,a))
```

the model is working as expected without raising any error.

EDIT:

My question is different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001922/failedpreconditionerror-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-in-tensorflow). I was already aware of

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
```

but I didn't know that it should have been performed after the optimization too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this piece of code:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
```

after having created these tensors:

```
y_batch , x_batch, a_batch = tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,1), name='y'), tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,2), name='x'), tf.placeholder("float64",shape=(None,1), name='a')
error = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y_batch - q_model(x_batch,a_batch))) / 100.
train = optimizer.minimize(error)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
```

Otherwise the hidden variables added to the Graph when calling the `optimiser.minimize` method won't be initialised.

Meantime, the call to `print sess.run(q_model(x,a))` works because the variables used by this part of the Graph have been all initialised.

BTW: Use `tf.global_variables_initializer` rather than `tf.initialize_all_variables`.

EDIT:

To perform a selective initialisation, you could do something like that:

```
with tf.variable_scope("to_be_initialised"):
    train = optimizer.minimize(error)

sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='to_be_initialised')))
```

Comment: yes but actually the reason I would't like to initialize the variable in this point is that I use q_model(X,A) with different X, A (for example plugging another model in the place of A). And thus if I have to initialize the variables every time that I change my X and A, I will loose the the values of W and b. While I would like to mantain them

Comment: Is there a way maybe just to initialize the hidden variable used by optimizer.minimize??

Comment: `X` and `A` are placeholders so they are designed to be changed at every call of `sess.run` without modifying values of `W` and `b`. If you call your `init` op only once, `W` and `b` will kept their values (subject to training update of course).

Comment: No,maybe I didn't explain very well the situation. take the definition of q_model(X,A). After having performed  the training of q_model(x,a) where x,a are placeholders, I would like to do the training of q_model(x,pi_model(x)) where pi_model is another tensorflow model (which for simplicity I didn't report here).

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I will create different optimizers in the beginning and initialize them , and then running the code. thanks

Comment: Hmm regarding your situation, it seems to me that if you call `q_model(x, pi_model(x))` later in your code you won't have to reinitialise your variables `W` and `b` (and therefore they will keep their value from the first part of the training) as they will be already part of your graph and you only need to reinitialise the new ones if any.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is much simpler for me. Thanks

Comment: There is a better way to do what you stated in 'EDIT', since: **WARNING:tensorflow:VARIABLES collection name is deprecated, please use GLOBAL_VARIABLES instead; VARIABLES will be removed after 2017-03-02.**