# Load multiple images to 4D tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to load multiple images from a directory and then stack them in **4D** **tensor**. I wrote the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
img=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([134,65,147,1]),dtype=tf.float32)
sess=tf.Session()
model=tf.global_variables_initializer()
dir_path = os.path.dirname('C:\\Users\\E6410\\Documents\\Masterarbeit\\specconvneu\\')
for i in range(134):
    filename = dir_path + "\\Spec_Test("+str(i+1)+").png"
    image = mpimg.imread(filename)
    image = tf.Variable(image,dtype=tf.float32)
    sess.run(model)
    image=tf.reshape(image,[65,147,1])
    img[i+1,:,:,:].assign(image)
    sess.run(img)
    sess.run(image)
```

The number of images is 134. Every image has a height of 65 and a width of 147. They have one channel.
I run my code and had the following Error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_344
     [[Node: Variable_344/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_344"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_344)]]
```

I understand that the compiler is trying to read the variable before initializing the variable. I tried to initialize it with different ways but always the same error. Could you help to correct the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a similar issue here. I think you should explicitly initialise all the variables in the beginning.

You can try the following

init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

Please refer to the following answer

[FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001922/failedpreconditionerror-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

You are performing lot of redundant computations here, following lines will solve the issue.

```
# I don't understand why are you using variable here?
image = tf.Variable(image,dtype=tf.float32)
# just convert the array to tensor
image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image,dtype=tf.float32)

#Also move the initialization line before for loop
sess.run(model)
for i in range(134)
```

Comment: I saw this way of using a variable in a tutorial. But I will try to use your way. Thank you

Comment: to stack them into a `4D tensor` you dont need to use all these codes. Just read the images using numpy and store them in a 4d `nparray` and `tf.convert_to_tensor`

Comment: Ok. It seems also a better idea.