# output and feeb_dict inside session FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorrt

I am converting the [MTCNN tensorflow](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow) into tensorflow tensorRT

When I run [camera_test.py](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow/blob/master/test/camera_test.py)

I get this error [FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001922/failedpreconditionerror-attempting-to-use-uninitialized-in-tensorflow)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1334, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1319, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value conv4_2/biases   [[{{node
>   conv4_2/biases/read}}]]    [[{{node Squeeze_1}}]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "camera_test_trrt.py", line
>   48, in 
>       boxes_c,landmarks = mtcnn_detector.detect(image)   File "../Detection/MtcnnDetector.py", line 371, in detect
>       boxes, boxes_c, _ = self.detect_pnet(img)   File "../Detection/MtcnnDetector.py", line 221, in detect_pnet
>       cls_cls_map, reg = self.pnet_detector.predict(im_resized)   File "../Detection/fcn_detector_trrt.py", line 56, in predict
>       self.height_op: height})   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 929, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1152, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1328, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 1348, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError:
>   Attempting to use uninitialized value conv4_2/biases   [[node
>   conv4_2/biases/read (defined at ../train_models/mtcnn_model.py:208) ]]
>      [[node Squeeze_1 (defined at ../train_models/mtcnn_model.py:245) ]]
>
> Caused by op 'conv4_2/biases/read', defined at:   File
>   "camera_test_trrt.py", line 23, in 
>       PNet = FcnDetector(P_Net, '/home/jetsonnano/Downloads/MTCNN-Tensorflow-master/test/p_output_graph_FP16.pb')
>   File "../Detection/fcn_detector_trrt.py", line 23, in **init**
>       self.cls_prob, self.bbox_pred, _ = net_factory(image_reshape, training=False)   File "../train_models/mtcnn_model.py", line 208, in
>   P_Net
>       bbox_pred = slim.conv2d(net,num_outputs=4,kernel_size=[1,1],stride=1,scope='conv4_2',activation_fn=None)
>   File
>   "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 182, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1158, in convolution2d
>       conv_dims=2)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 182, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1061, in convolution
>       outputs = layer.apply(inputs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 1227, in apply
>       return self.**call**(inputs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 530, in **call**
>       outputs = super(Layer, self).**call**(inputs, *args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 538, in **call**
>       self._maybe_build(inputs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 1603, in _maybe_build
>       self.build(input_shapes)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py",
>   line 174, in build
>       dtype=self.dtype)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py",
>   line 435, in add_weight
>       getter=vs.get_variable)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 349, in add_weight
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py",
>   line 607, in _add_variable_with_custom_getter
>       **kwargs_for_getter)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 1479, in get_variable
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 1220, in get_variable
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 530, in get_variable
>       return custom_getter(**custom_getter_kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1753, in layer_variable_getter
>       return _model_variable_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py",
>   line 1744, in _model_variable_getter
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 182, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 350, in model_variable
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/arg_scope.py",
>   line 182, in func_with_args
>       return func(*args, **current_args)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 277, in variable
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 499, in _true_getter
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 911, in _get_single_variable
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 213, in **call**
>       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 176, in _variable_v1_call
>       aggregation=aggregation)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 155, in 
>       previous_getter = lambda **kwargs: default_variable_creator(None, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py",
>   line 2495, in default_variable_creator
>       expected_shape=expected_shape, import_scope=import_scope)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 217, in **call**
>       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File
>   "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 1395, in **init**
>       constraint=constraint)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py",
>   line 1557, in _init_from_args
>       self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")   File
>   "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py",
>   line 180, in wrapper
>       return target(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 81, in identity
>       ret = gen_array_ops.identity(input, name=name)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 3890, in identity
>       "Identity", input=input, name=name)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 788, in _apply_op_helper
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py",
>   line 507, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3300, in create_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "/home/jetsonnano/.virtualenvs/jetsonnanotest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1801, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
>
> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>   uninitialized value conv4_2/biases     [[node conv4_2/biases/read
>   (defined at ../train_models/mtcnn_model.py:208) ]]     [[node Squeeze_1
>   (defined at ../train_models/mtcnn_model.py:245) ]]

how do i `tf.global_variables_initializer` will `sess.run`

```
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)
```

When I have `output parameters` and `feed_dict` in `sess.run`

[cls_prob, bbox_pred,landmark_pred = self.sess.run([self.cls_prob, self.bbox_pred,self.landmark_pred], feed_dict={self.image_op: data})](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow/blob/master/Detection/detector.py?#L65)
 in `detector.py`

and

[cls_prob, bbox_pred = self.sess.run([self.cls_prob, self.bbox_pred],feed_dict={self.image_op: databatch, self.width_op: width,self.height_op: height})](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow/blob/master/Detection/fcn_detector.py?#L41)
 in `fcn_detector.py`

can anyone help out here?

Comment: Can you try `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead of the current one?

Comment: @learner `self.session` has input parameters `class_probability` and `box_prediction` along with `feed_dict`. passing `tf.global_variables_initializer` would not help

Comment: If you have access to the `sess=tf.Session()` object you can always do `sess.run(<command_here>)` without passing `feed_dict`. Also I don't get why `self.session` would have "input parameters"

Comment: get this error `ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'init' type=NoOp> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init"
op: "NoOp"
 is not an element of this graph.)`

Comment: Just after `self.sess = tf.Session(
                config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)))` this line, declare `init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()` and do `self.sess.run(init_op)`

Comment: Tried it but no detection of face happening

Comment: Is the error targeted in the question gone?

Comment: No error, model runs but no face detection

Comment: Okay, I'm going to add this as an answer. As to why the code is not working, that doesn't fall in the scope of this question. Please mark it as accepted, as the answer solves the original problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after [the following line](https://github.com/AITTSMD/MTCNN-Tensorflow/blob/master/Detection/detector.py?#L65)

```py
self.sess = tf.Session( config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)))
```

declare

```py
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

and do

```py
self.sess.run(init_op)
```