# In TensorFlow is there any way to just initialize uninitialised variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The standard way of initializing variables in TensorFlow is

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

After running some learning for a while I create a new set of variables but once I initialize them it resets all my existing variables. At the moment my way around this is to save all the variable I need and then reapply them after the tf.initalize_all_variables call. This works but is a bit ugly and clunky. I cannot find anything like this in the docs...

Does anyone know of any good way to just initialize the uninitialized variables?

Comment: The `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize(loss)` function is [defined to be in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize) `optim.apply_gradients(optim.compute_gradients(loss))`. This would make your example the same as mine, except you throw out all the `None`s. Can you run the `train_step` after that? When I ran it, all the slots were `None` so the optimizer remained uninitialized and the neural network failed to run.

Comment: Here is an example of a [simple function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43601894/1090562) that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no elegant* way to enumerate the uninitialized variables in a graph. However, if you have access to the new variable objects—let's call them `v_6`, `v_7`, and `v_8`—you can selectively initialize them using [`tf.initialize_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#initialize_variables):

```
init_new_vars_op = tf.initialize_variables([v_6, v_7, v_8])
sess.run(init_new_vars_op)
```

---

* A process of trial and error could be used to identify the uninitialized variables, as follows:

```
uninitialized_vars = []
for var in tf.all_variables():
    try:
        sess.run(var)
    except tf.errors.FailedPreconditionError:
        uninitialized_vars.append(var)

init_new_vars_op = tf.initialize_variables(uninitialized_vars)
# ...
```

...however, I would not condone such behavior :-).

Comment: Tensorflow 0.9 has the function tf.report_uninitialized_variables() that may be useful.

Comment: tf.initialize_variables has been deprecated. Use the equivalent https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer

Answer (score 30):

**UPDATE:** TensorFlow 0.9 has a new method that "fixes" all this **but only if you're using a [VariableScope](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#VariableScope) with `reuse` set to `True`**. [tf.report_uninitialized_variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#report_uninitialized_variables) which can be used in one line with `sess.run( tf.initialize_variables( list( tf.get_variable(name) for name in sess.run( tf.report_uninitialized_variables( tf.all_variables( ) ) ) ) ) )`

or more intelligently through the ability to specify the variables you expect to be initialized:

```
def guarantee_initialized_variables(session, list_of_variables = None):
    if list_of_variables is None:
        list_of_variables = tf.all_variables()
    uninitialized_variables = list(tf.get_variable(name) for name in
                                   session.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables(list_of_variables)))
    session.run(tf.initialize_variables(uninitialized_variables))
    return unintialized_variables
```

This is still less ideal than actually knowing which variables are and are not initialized and taking care of that properly, but in the case of misdirection like the `optim` classes (see below) it may be hard to avoid.

Also note, tf.initialize_variables cannot evaluate tf.report_uninitialized_variables, so both of them have to be run within the context of the session to work.

---

There is an inelegant but concise way to do it. Before introducing your new variables run `temp = set(tf.all_variables())` and afterwards run `sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(set(tf.all_variables()) - temp))`. These together will only initialize any variables created after the temp value is assigned.

I've been playing with transfer learning, so I wanted a quick way to do it too, but this is the best way I could find. Especially when using things like AdamOptimizer, which doesn't give you easy (or any, I'm not sure) access to the variables it uses. So the following actually shows up in my code. (I initialize the new layer's variables explicitly, and run it once to show the initial error before transfer learning. Just for a sanity check.)

```
temp = set(tf.all_variables())
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
#I honestly don't know how else to initialize ADAM in TensorFlow.
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables(set(tf.all_variables()) - temp))
```

And it solves all my problems.

**EDIT:** [@Lifu_Huang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37291254/786020) states the proper way to fix my problem. Theoretically, you should use [tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot_names](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.get_slot_names) and [tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.get_slot):

```
optim = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(1e-4)
loss = cross_entropy(y,yhat)
train_step = optim.minimize(loss)
sess.run(tf.initialize_variables([optim.get_slot(loss, name)
                                  for name in optim.get_slot_names()])
```

This however gives me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initializer'`. I'll make edits when I figure out what I did wrong, so you don't make my mistakes.

Comment: I've reproduced the `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'initializer'` issue.

Comment: Note that despite the slots, there can be other vars created by the optimizer. `AdamOptimizer` for me also creates the vars `[<tf.Variable 'optimize/beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'optimize/beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>]` which do not correspond to a trainable var, thus you don't get them as slots.

Answer (score 27):

TF [does not have a function that does exactly what you want](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/state_ops), but you can easily write one:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def initialize_uninitialized(sess):
    global_vars          = tf.global_variables()
    is_initialized   = sess.run([tf.is_variable_initialized(var) for var in global_vars])
    not_initialized_vars = [v for (v, f) in zip(global_vars, is_initialized) if not f]
    
    print [str(i.name) for i in not_initialized_vars] # only for testing
    if len(not_initialized_vars):
        sess.run(tf.variables_initializer(not_initialized_vars))
```

Here I extract all [global variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables), iterate all of them and check whether they [are already initialized](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/is_variable_initialized). After this I get a list of uninitialized variables which I [initialize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer). I also print variables that I am going to initialize for debugging purposes.

---

You can easily verify that it works as expected:

```
a = tf.Variable(3, name='my_var_a')
b = tf.Variable(4, name='my_var_b')

sess = tf.Session()
initialize_uninitialized(sess)
initialize_uninitialized(sess)

c = tf.Variable(5, name='my_var_a') # the same name, will be resolved to different name
d = tf.Variable(6, name='my_var_d')
initialize_uninitialized(sess)

print '\n\n', sess.run([a, b, c, d])
```

This will print all the unitialized variables before initializing them and the last sess.run will make sure persuade you that all variables are initialized.

---

You can also use [`tf.report_uninitialized_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/report_uninitialized_variables) to write a similar function. A sketch of it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276281/1090562).

Comment: Great Answer.  You got my vote.  Would using  `tf.report_uninitialized_variables() ` be a better approach?

Comment: @PaulO in my opinion both approaches are similar and I can't say that any of them is better.

Comment: Then first link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

For the case @Poik mentioned, when variables are created by optimizers so that they cannot be accessed directly, a cleaner solution is to use `tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot`.

Some optimizer subclasses, such as `MomentumOptimizer` and `AdagradOptimizer` allocate and manage additional variables associated with the variables to train. These are called Slots. You can use `tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot_names()` to get all slot names a optimizer has and then use `tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot` to get the variable allocated for these slots.

Comment: This answer isn't actually usable yet, since `tf.train.Optimizer.get_slot` returns `None` for the slots until the optimizer creates the variables needed, which will happen when `minimize` is run for the first time. Getting around this requires calling the undocumented function `tf.train.Optimizer._zeros_slot()` or others which you should never do if you want documented support and to be able to use future updates of TensorFlow.

Comment: Note that despite the slots, there can be other vars created by the optimizer. `AdamOptimizer` for me also creates the vars `[<tf.Variable 'optimize/beta1_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'optimize/beta2_power:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>]` which do not correspond to a trainable var, thus you don't get them as slots.

Answer (score 4):

I've come up with a method for TensorFlow r0.11:

```
def get_uninitialized_variables(variables=None):
    """Get uninitialized variables as a list.

    Parameters
    ----------
    variables : collections.Iterable[tf.Variable]
        Return only uninitialized variables within this collection.
        If not specified, will return all uninitialized variables.

    Returns
    -------
    list[tf.Variable]
    """
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    if variables is None:
        variables = tf.all_variables()
    else:
        variables = list(variables)
    init_flag = sess.run(
        tf.pack([tf.is_variable_initialized(v) for v in variables]))
    return [v for v, f in zip(variables, init_flag) if not f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Btw, if you want to initialize only a single tensor (for e.g.  `tf.Variable`) that hasn't been initialized using `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, then you can use `your_tensor.initializer` in the `sess.run()` as in the following example:

```
In [196]: weights = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(3, 4)), name='weights')

In [197]: with tf.Session() as sess:
     ...:     sess.run(weights.initializer)
     ...:     print(weights.eval())
     ...:     

# the result
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to create all the training operators first and initialize variables afterwards.

For example, I solved the problem of layer-wise pretraining with Adam Optimizer in the following way:

```
 # create an optimizer
 pretrain_optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

 # Make an array of the trainers for all the layers
 trainers=[pretrain_optimizer.minimize(loss_reconstruction(ae.run_less_layers(ae._input_, i+1), ae.run_less_layers(ae._input_, i+1, is_target=True)), global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step(), name='Layer_wise_optimizer_'+str(i)) for i in xrange(len(ae_shape) - 2)]

 # Initialize all the variables
 sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```