# How to initialise only optimizer variables in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use `MomentumOptimizer` in Tensorflow. However, since this optimizer uses some internal variable, attempting to use it without initializing this variable yields an error:

> `FailedPreconditionError` (see above for traceback): Attempting to use
>    uninitialized value `Variable_2/Momentum`

This can be easily solved by initializing all variables, using for example

```
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

However, I do not want to initialize **all** the variables - only those of optimizer. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a more straightforward way:

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
session.run(tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables()))
```

Comment: Whoa, that looks pretty nice! I have not used Tensorflow in a while, but it seems like a new API function?

Comment: `.variables()` method in `Optimizer` was added at some moment between tensorflow 1.4 and 1.8.

Answer (score 21):

Both current answers kinda work by filtering the variable name using the 'Momentum' string. But that is very brittle on two sides:

1. It could silently (re-)initialize some other variables you don't actually want to reset! Either simply because of a name-clash, or because you have a more complex graph and optimize different parts separately, for example.
2. It will only work for one specific optimizer, and how do you know the names to look out for for others?
3. Bonus: an update to tensorflow might **silently** break your code.

Fortunately, tensorflow's abstract `Optimizer` class has a mechanism for that, these extra optimizer variables are called ["slots"](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#slots), and you can get all slot names of an optimizer using the [`get_slot_names()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#get_slot_names) method:

```
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(...)
print(opt.get_slot_names())
# prints ['momentum']
```

And you can get the variable corresponding to the slot for a specific (trainable) variable `v` using the [`get_slot(var, slot_name)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#get_slot) method:

```
opt.get_slot(some_var, 'momentum')
```

Putting all this together, you can create an op that initializes the optimizer's state as follows:

```
var_list = # list of vars to optimize, e.g. 
           # tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(0.1, 0.95)
step_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=var_list)
reset_opt_op = tf.variables_initializer([opt.get_slot(var, name) for name in opt.get_slot_names() for var in var_list])
```

This will really only reset the correct variables, and be robust across optimizers.

Except for one [unfortunate caveat](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8057): `AdamOptimizer`. That one also keeps a counter for how often it's been called. That means you should really think hard about what you're doing here anyways, but for completeness' sake, you can get its extra states as `opt._get_beta_accumulators()`. The returned list should be added to the list in the above `reset_opt_op` line.

Answer (score 11):

You can filter variables by name and only initialize those. IE

```
momentum_initializers = [var.initializer for var in tf.global_variables() if 'Momentum' in var.name]
sess.run(momentum_initializers)
```

Comment: Works. Add prefix to own variables (that u wanna keep) and those (without prefix || has slash in its name) are those shall be initialized.

Answer (score 6):

Building off of LucasB's answer about `AdamOptimizer`, this function takes an `AdamOptimizer` instance `adam_opt` that has its `Variables` created (one of these two called: `adam_opt.minimize(loss, var_list=var_list)` or `adam_opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, var_list))`. The function creates an `Op` that, when called, re-initializes the optimizer's variables for the passed variable, as well as the global counting state.

```
def adam_variables_initializer(adam_opt, var_list):
    adam_vars = [adam_opt.get_slot(var, name)
                 for name in adam_opt.get_slot_names()
                 for var in var_list if var is not None]
    adam_vars.extend(list(adam_opt._get_beta_accumulators()))
    return tf.variables_initializer(adam_vars)
```

e.g.:

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4)
fit_op = opt.minimize(loss, var_list=var_list)
reset_opt_vars = adam_variables_initializer(opt, var_list)
```

Comment: In my case adam_vars list may contain variables of type None, not sure if there is an elegant way to solve it...currently I just filter them all

Comment: @TamakiSakura hm which ones? I updated the answer with a filter in the list comprehension

Comment: ```[adam_opt.get_slot(var, name) for name in adam_opt.get_slot_names() for var in var_list]``` part, I am sure my var_list does not contain None. What I currently do is very ugly: ```adam_vars = filter(lambda x: x is not None, adam_vars)``` before calling ```tf.variables_initalizer```

Answer (score 2):

[`tf.variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer) seems to be the preferred way to initialize a specific set of variables:

```
var_list = [var for var in tf.global_variables() if 'Momentum' in var.name]
var_list_init = tf.variables_initializer(var_list)
...
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(var_list_init)
```

Comment: It supposed to be: var_list = [var for var in tf.global_variables() if 'Momentum' in var.name]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the None problem just do:

```
  self.opt_vars = [opt.get_slot(var, name) for name in opt.get_slot_names() 
                   for var in self.vars_to_train
                   if opt.get_slot(var, name) is not None]
```