# How to get the list of uninitialized variables from tf.report_uninitialized_variables

Tags: tensorflow

The documentation says it's a 1 d tensor, however, I have failed to figure out how to access the list.

I would prefer the actual variables rather than names as I would like to initialize them via `tf.variables_initializer()`

Comment: Do you need to figure out how to use this function or do you actually need to initialize uninitialized vars?

Comment: @SalvadorDali I saw and commented on you answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164529/in-tensorflow-is-there-any-way-to-just-initialize-uninitialised-variables  and was trying to figure out if I could get the actual variables from it or just the names.

Comment: Understood, so you just want to find out how to use this function. Will try to answer it later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`tf.report_uninitialized_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/report_uninitialized_variables) gives you a tensor with the names of the variables. So it will be way more ugly (in my opinion) than my [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601894/1090562).

You will need to find all the variables corresponding to names you got from `report_uninitialized_variables` and they use them in your `tf.variables_initializer()`. Something like this:

```
tf.variables_initializer(
    [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name.split(':')[0] in set(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
])
```

Comment: TY @SalvadorDali