# Tensorflow Error: Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power_18

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

This is my code in tensorflow for simple neural network:

```python
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Model:
    def __init__(self,input_neuron=2,hidden_neuron=10,output_neuron=2):
        self.input_neuron = input_neuron
        self.hidden_neuron = hidden_neuron
        self.output_neuron = output_neuron
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.input_neuron])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.output_neuron])
        self.model = self.graph()
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())



    @staticmethod
    def one_hot_encode(y):
        y_ = np.zeros((len(y),2))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            y_[i,y[i][0]]=1

        return y_

    def graph(self):
        w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_neuron,self.hidden_neuron]))
        l1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.x,w1))
        w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hidden_neuron,self.output_neuron]))
        l2=tf.matmul(l1,w2)

        return l2

    def train(self,xTrain,yTrain):
        yTrain = self.one_hot_encode(yTrain)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
                             logits=self.model,labels=self.y))
        train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
        for epoch in range(100):
            self.sess.run(train,feed_dict={self.x:xTrain,self.y:yTrain})

    def predict(self,xTest):
        prediction = tf.argmax(self.model)
        return self.sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:xTest})
```

When I run this using :

```
model = Model()
xTrain = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
yTrain = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
model.train(xTrain,yTrain)
```

I'm getting this error:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value beta1_power_18

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the `self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` in the __init__ of your `Model` class, but only in the `train()` method do you set up the `tf.train.AdamOptimizer()`. The latter also creates some variables that need to be initialized. Move the

```
self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

line ***right after***

```
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
```

and it will work.

Full code (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Model:
    def __init__(self,input_neuron=2,hidden_neuron=10,output_neuron=2):
        self.input_neuron = input_neuron
        self.hidden_neuron = hidden_neuron
        self.output_neuron = output_neuron
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.input_neuron])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.output_neuron])
        self.model = self.graph()
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

    @staticmethod
    def one_hot_encode(y):
        y_ = np.zeros((len(y),2))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            y_[i,y[i][0]]=1

        return y_

    def graph(self):
        w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_neuron,self.hidden_neuron]))
        l1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.x,w1))
        w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hidden_neuron,self.output_neuron]))
        l2=tf.matmul(l1,w2)

        return l2

    def train(self,xTrain,yTrain):
        yTrain = self.one_hot_encode(yTrain)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
                             logits=self.model,labels=self.y))
        train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(100):
            self.sess.run(train,feed_dict={self.x:xTrain,self.y:yTrain})
        print("Training done!")

    def predict(self,xTest):
        prediction = tf.argmax(self.model)
        return self.sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:xTest})

model = Model()
xTrain = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
yTrain = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
model.train(xTrain,yTrain)
```

Based on your comment, if you don't want to re-initialize the whole network at each call of the `train()` method, then you need to initialize the network at the `__init__()` method and use [`tf.report_uninitialized_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/report_uninitialized_variables) to get all the uninitialized ones an initialize only those in `train()`. I wrote the method `initialize_uninitialized()` to do that, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44276281/4320693) to a question by [Salvador Dali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090562/salvador-dali).

Full code (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

class Model:
    def __init__(self,input_neuron=2,hidden_neuron=10,output_neuron=2):
        self.input_neuron = input_neuron
        self.hidden_neuron = hidden_neuron
        self.output_neuron = output_neuron
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.input_neuron])
        self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,self.output_neuron])
        self.model = self.graph()
        self.sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    @staticmethod
    def one_hot_encode(y):
        y_ = np.zeros((len(y),2))
        for i in range(len(y)):
            y_[i,y[i][0]]=1

        return y_

    def graph(self):
        w1=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.input_neuron,self.hidden_neuron]))
        l1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.x,w1))
        w2=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hidden_neuron,self.output_neuron]))
        l2=tf.matmul(l1,w2)

        return l2

    def initialize_uninitialized( self ):
        uninitialized_variables = [v for v in tf.global_variables()
            if v.name.split(':')[0] in set(self.sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables())) ]
        self.sess.run( tf.variables_initializer( uninitialized_variables ) )

    def train(self,xTrain,yTrain):
        yTrain = self.one_hot_encode(yTrain)
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
                             logits=self.model,labels=self.y))
        train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
        self.initialize_uninitialized()

        for epoch in range(100):
            self.sess.run(train,feed_dict={self.x:xTrain,self.y:yTrain})
        print("Training done!")

    def predict(self,xTest):
        prediction = tf.argmax(self.model)
        return self.sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={x:xTest}) 

model = Model()
xTrain = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
yTrain = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])
model.train(xTrain,yTrain)
```

Comment: but would it not initialise my variables w1 and w2, each time I'll call the train method. I need to save that variables, so that when i call model.train next time, it should start training from the last saved values

Comment: Added another version to my answer in light of this comment