# Tensorflow finding matching strings in tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm trying to find variables that end in `train_step` from `tf.report_uninitialized_variables(),` but you can't iterate over tensors without `eager execution.` I get that you need to use `tf.map_fn,` but I do not understand it well enough.

This is what I have:

```
variables = []
for s, t in zip(tf.report_uninitialized_variables().eval(session=sess), 
                tf.report_uninitialized_variables()):
    if 'train_step' in s:
        variables.append(t)
train_step_init = tf.variables_initializer(variables, name='train_step_init')
```

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268206/how-to-get-the-list-of-uninitialized-variables-from-tf-report-uninitialized-vari

Comment: @syltruong `[v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name.split(':')[0] in set(sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()))
]` just returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I could do:

```
variables = []
for i, v in enumerate(tf.global_variables()):
    name = v.name.split(':')[0].encode('ASCII')
    if name in sess.run(tf.report_uninitialized_variables()[0]):
        if b'train_step' in name:
            variables.append(v)

train_step_init = tf.variables_initializer(variables)
sess.run(train_step_init)
```