# Uninitialized value error while using Adadelta optimizer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I am trying to build a CNN using Adagrad optimizer but am getting the following error.

**tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_7/Adadelta**

**[[Node: Adadelta/update_Variable_7/ApplyAdadelta = ApplyAdadelta[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_7"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_7, Variable_7/Adadelta, Variable_7/Adadelta_1, Adadelta/lr, Adadelta/rho, Adadelta/epsilon, gradients/add_3_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1)]]
Caused by op u'Adadelta/update_Variable_7/ApplyAdadelta',**

**optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)**

I tried reinitializing the session variables after the adagrad statement as mentioned in this post, but that didn't help too.

How can I avoid this error? Thanks.

[Tensorflow: Using Adam optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788989/tensorflow-using-adam-optimizer)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 100
batch_size = 1000
display_step = 1


# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]), name="weights")
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="bias")

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])


W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])


W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):

            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            x_image = tf.reshape(batch_xs, [-1,28,28,1])

            h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
            h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

            h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
            h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

            h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
            h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)


            y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

            cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(batch_ys * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
            #optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

            optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)
            sess.run(init)

            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(batch_ys,1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
            sess.run([cross_entropy, y_conv,optimizer])
            print cross_entropy.eval()
```

Comment: First, I really think the model should be out of the loop. Put h_*, cross_entropy, optimizer, accuracy, etc. after "b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])" line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that [`tf.initialize_all_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#initialize_all_variables) is a misleading name. It really means "return an operation that initializes all variables that have already been created (in the default graph)". When you call `tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(...).minimize()`, TensorFlow creates *additional* variables, which are not covered by the `init` op that you created earlier.

Moving the line:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

...**after** the construction of the `tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer` should make your program work.

**N.B.** Your program rebuilds the entire network, apart from the variables, on each training step. This is likely to be very inefficient, and the Adadelta algorithm will not adapt as expected because its state is recreated on each step. I would strongly recommend moving the code from the definition of `batch_xs` to the creation of the `optimizer` outside of the two nested `for` loops. You should define `tf.placeholder()` ops for the `batch_xs` and `batch_ys` inputs, and use the `feed_dict` argument to `sess.run()` to pass in the values returned by `mnist.train.next_batch()`.